# Error while creating Logic App Standard in Azure

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'm getting an error while trying to deploy the Logic App Standard using CI/CD pipelines.

```
mError: **m**mcreating Logic App Standard: (Site Name "testinglogicapp" / Resource Group "logicapptesting"): ***b.AppsClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=*** -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=<nil> <nil>**m
│**m **m
```

I'm not sure what exactly this means.
Here's the terraform module that i'm using

```
resource "azurerm_logic_app_standard" "logicapp" {
  for_each                   = local.logicapp_map
  app_service_plan_id        = var.serviceplan_map[each.value.serviceplan_key]
  location                   = var.resourcelocation
  name                       = "testinglogicapp"
  resource_group_name        = var.resourcegpname
  storage_account_name       = var.storageaccountname
  storage_account_access_key = var.storageaccesskey
  https_only                 = true
  virtual_network_subnet_id  = var.subnet_id
  version                    = each.value.version
  
  app_settings = {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME" = each.value.worker_runtime
    "WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION" = "~18"
  }
  site_config {
    always_on = false
  }
  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
  tags = merge(var.rgtags, var.ars_tags)
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      tags
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using same delegated Subnet which was used by other resource. It needed a new one.

Comment: Did this solve the problem you were facing? If yes, please mark this as answer.

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked for me:

```
locals {
  logicapp_map = {
    "logicapp1" = {
      serviceplan_key  = "app_service_plan_dotnet"
      version          = "2022-03-01"
      worker_runtime   = "dotnet"
    },
    "logicapp2" = {
      serviceplan_key  = "app_service_plan_python"
      version          = "2022-03-01"
      worker_runtime   = "python"
    },
  }
  
}


resource "azurerm_app_service_plan" "example" {
    for_each                   = local.logicapp_map
  name                = each.key
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  kind                = "elastic"


  sku {
    tier = "WorkflowStandard"
    size = "WS1"
  }
}


resource "azurerm_logic_app_standard" "logicapp" {
  for_each                   = local.logicapp_map
  app_service_plan_id     = azurerm_app_service_plan.example[each.key].id
  location                   = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  name                       = "testinglogicapp-${each.key}"
  resource_group_name        = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  storage_account_name       = azurerm_storage_account.example.name
  storage_account_access_key = azurerm_storage_account.example.primary_access_key
  https_only                 = true
  version                    = each.value.version
  
  app_settings = {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME" = each.value.worker_runtime
    "WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION" = "~18"
  }
  site_config {
    always_on = false
  }
  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
}
```

**Note:**

> Check that your Azure credentials are valid and has necessary
> permissions to create resources .And make sure every time logic app
> has new name created so that  there are no conflicting resources in
> the target resource group
>
> Make sure required properties and version of the Logic App Standard
> resource are valid .

**`terraform apply`**
[image]

[image]

**Reference** : [azurerm_logic_app_standard | Resources | hashicorp/azurerm | Terraform Registry](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/logic_app_standard)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the App service Plan

`app_service_plan_id = var.serviceplan_map[each.value.serviceplan_key]`

you are using is not an Isolated Sku. I too faced the similar error, but i'm getting this error only when I try to use the isolated SKU for app service plan.

Issue is resolved when I changed the App Service plan SKU as WS1 or any standard type.

Azurerm_logic_app_standard resource seems not supporting the isolated SKU types for app service plans.

Please post your suggestions on this answer.